# Sharing data within template

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a template named `exercise`. Template `exercise` is subscribed to exactly one exercise (data) from db.

I am building touch typing app. The template `exercise` is part where user writes down prepared text.

This template will be quite complicated.

I needed some additional logic, so I created class `ExerciseText`.

**The goal is:** I need to share object `exerciseText` within template helpers and events of template `exercise`. I need that object `exerciseText`have some state during live time of template `exercise`.

I wrote my code with help of [Sacha's article](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/)

It works, but is this a good pattern? Thank you for any ideas.

ExerciseText.js

```
"use strict";

export default class ExerciseText {
    constructor(exercise) {
        this.text = exercise.text;
    }

    get getText() {
        return this.text.split('');
    }

    // many logic wow
}
```

exercise.js

```
"use strict";

import ExerciseText from '../../../imports/api/client/ExerciseText.js';

Template.exercise.helpers({
    exercise: () => {
        if (Template.instance().subscription.ready()) {
            return Template.instance().exercise;
        }
    },
    text: () => {
        if (Template.instance().subscription.ready()) {
            return Template.instance().exerciseText.getText;
        }
    }
});

Template.exercise.onCreated(()=> {
    var instance = this;
    instance.autorun(() => {
        var params = Router.current().params;
        var lessonUrl = params.lessonUrl;
        var exerciseOrder = parseInt(params.rank);

        instance.subscription = instance.subscribe('exercise', lessonUrl, exerciseOrder);
        if (instance.subscription.ready()) {
            var lesson = Lessons.findOne() || {};
            if (lesson.hasOwnProperty('exercises')) {
                // lesson has only one published exercise
                // there si only one element in that array
                instance.exercise = lesson.exercises[0];
                instance.exerciseText = new ExerciseText(instance.exercise);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I want to answer this question, but it's unclear what the final goal is, can you explain what you are trying to show?

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question.